# Считывание из файла в структуру C

Tags: c

Друзья! Не могу найти ошибку в коде - она либо в месте считывания структуры, либо на месте вывода её в другой файл.
Ввод:

```
while ((c = fgetc(fp)) != EOF) {
        ungetc(c, fp);
        fscanf(fp, "%d", &stud_list[i].group);
        do { c = fgetc(fp); } while (c != '\n' && c != EOF);

        fgets(stud_list[i].surname, 50, fp);
        stud_list[i].surname[strcspn(stud_list[i].surname, "\n")] = 0;

        fgets(stud_list[i].name, 50, fp);
        stud_list[i].name[strcspn(stud_list[i].name, "\n")] = 0;

        fgets(stud_list[i].patronymic, 50, fp);
        stud_list[i].patronymic[strcspn(stud_list[i].patronymic, "\n")] = 0;

        fscanf(fp, "%d", &stud_list[i].year);
        do { c = fgetc(fp); } while (c != '\n' && c != EOF);

        for (j = 0; j < 4; j++)
        fscanf(fp, "%d ", &stud_list[i].marks[j]);
        fscanf(fp, "%d", &stud_list[i].marks[4]);
        i++;
    }
```

Вывод:

```
while (stud_list[t].group) {
    fprintf(fp, "%d\n", stud_list[t].group);

    fputs(stud_list[t].surname, fp);
    fputc('\n', fp);
    fputs(stud_list[t].name, fp);
    fputc('\n', fp);
    fputs(stud_list[t].patronymic, fp);
    fputc('\n', fp);

    fprintf(fp, "%d\n", stud_list[t].year);
    for (j=0;j<4;j++)
    fprintf(fp, "%d ", stud_list[t].marks[j]);
    fprintf(fp, "%d\n", stud_list[t].marks[4]);
    t++;
}
```

Что я должен получить в выходном файле:

```
11
Иванов
Иван
Иванович
1990
5 5 5 5 5
12
Маяковский
Владимир
Владимирович
1893
5 5 5 5 4
```

И что получаю:

```
11
Иванов
Иван
Иванович
1990
5 5 5 5 12
12
Маяковский
Владимир
Владимирович
1893
5 5 5 5 4
4



0
0 0 0 0 0
```

Спасибо за помощь!

Comment: Почему не приведены объявления типов данных??? Какого размера массив `marks[]`? Почему не приведены входные данные?

Comment: @AnT я указал неправильный размер marks, из-за этого не работало. Спасибо за наводку.

Answer (score 0):

Непонятно, почему при выводе вы используете счётчик цикла:

У Вас лишний раз отрабатывает цикл печати. Происходит это из-за неправильной работы цикла ввода. После оператора

```
do { c = fgetc(fp); } while (c != '\n' && c != EOF);
```

Надо поставить нечто вроде

```
if (c == EOF)  break;
```

А сейчас у Вас выполняется лишний раз цикл ввода. Что и приводит к лишнему циклу вывода...

Comment: Всё равно не работает. Вывод остаётся тот же.

Comment: **Всё равно не работает.**   - f xnj Вы изменили, можно исходы посмотреть?  Просто поправьте текст в первом сообщении.